# Issues with posting to php page using SBJSON on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, sbjson

I am lending the code from a previous project I have done where it worked perfectly. I have tested the page separately which outputs the data using jQuery and it works fine so I know it is an issue within xcode.

I am using the following code which takes an NSDictionary containing the post data used to get the correct return data:

```
-(NSDictionary *)loadData:(NSDictionary *) sendDict{
    SBJsonWriter *writer = [SBJsonWriter new];
    NSString * jsonData = [writer stringWithObject:sendDict];
    NSString * getString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@", jsonData];

    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [getString UTF8String] length: [getString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://divisi.co.uk/YTA/custom_api.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Returned Json: %@", returnString);

    // decoding the json
    NSDictionary *loginArray = [NSDictionary alloc];
    loginArray = [returnString JSONValue];

    if([[loginArray objectForKey:@"SC"] isEqualToString:@"200"]){
        return [loginArray objectForKey:@"data"];
    }
    else{
        return [loginArray objectForKey:@"error_message"];
    }
}
```

When I send the post request it finds null on the php side and the json this encodes to be posted is `{"method":"getWhatsOn"}`, very simple. My test php page just gets this method name and prints it back encoded correctly i.e. `{"SC":"200","data":"getWhatsOn"}`. Which works in browser using jQuery as I mentioned, but in php the $_POST['method'] returns null when the request comes from the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *Sc= @"200";
 NSString *dataD=@"getWhatsOn";
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [dictionnary setObject:Sc forKey:@"firstString"];
 [dictionnary setObject:dataD forKey:@"secondfield"];

 NSError *error = nil;
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
 options:kNilOptions
 error:&error];   

 NSString *urlString = @"your URL";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

 // Prepare the request
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
 [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];    

 NSError *errorReturned = nil;
 NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
 returningResponse:&theResponse
 error:&errorReturned];
 if (errorReturned) 
 {
 //...handle the error
 }
 else 
 {
 NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@", retVal);

 }
```

Comment: You should add some explanations around your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I still get the same issue too when using this method. my dictionary is how it should be. Just something is wrong in the mechanism to post the Dictionary.